# What is this Quad monitor cable for?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I saw this on ebay...

[Matrox KX20-to-DVI Quad-Monitor Cable-1 x KX20-4x DVI-1](http://cgi.ebay.com/Matrox-KX20-to-DVI-Quad-Monitor-Cable-1-x-KX20-4x-DVI-1_W0QQitemZ270524057240QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_2?hash=item3efc7d8698#ht_761wt_958)

I am curious is it able to run multiple monitors from a single video card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like it is only for use with [Matrox's QID LP](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/qid_series/qidlppci/?productTabs=1) range of cards.

KX20 seems to be a propriety Matrox interface and this cable is required to attach 4 DVI monitors to the card

EDIT: In fact the Ebay listing explicitly states this:

```
Compatibility:
    Matrox graphic cards: 
    QID LP PCIe
    QID-P128LPAF
```

Answer (score 3):

As Shevek posted, KX20 is a proprietary Matrox interface. It allows you to use up to 4 digital or analog monitors. But they have different outputs, unlike sblair said. Here's a [link](http://www.boston.co.uk/products/qid-e128lpa.aspx) with some product info about the card that has this interface.

Comment: Also for reference you may come across a similar Nvidia cable, which would be specific to the NVS workstation cards.  It does the same thing as described here by Roald van Doom and Shevek.  These are proprietary cables and must be used with the correct multi display card to function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a splitter cable, which means that the input video is copied to all four outputs. So, it should be able to drive multiple monitors, but each monitor will display the same output.

Comment: This is not the case, this is a proprietary matrox interface that allows for a Quad display (spanned or mirrored, or even a single very high resolution display similar to apples dual-DVI requirement for 30" cinema display) to occupy only one slot on the back of your PC. It is not a DVI splitter.

Comment: @Dan Agreed, but the term "splitter" normally refers to mirrored outputs - the majority of video and audio "splitters" will simply mirror the output.